# How to resolve compilation error: warning "Files using this header must be compiled with _SVID_SOURCE or _XOPEN_SOURCE"

Tags: c

My code compilation is failing with below error.

```
/usr/include/sys/ipc.h:25:3: error: #warning "Files using this header must be compiled with _SVID_SOURCE or _XOPEN_SOURCE"
```

I tried `"#define _SVID_SOURCE 1"` before including header file "/usr/include/sys/ipc.h". But this did not work.

Comment: You should show the top level source code that includes this file, at least the part with all `#include`s and possible `#define`s. This code snippet should show where exactly you inserted `#define _SVID_SOURCE 1`. If the compiler output contains lines that show from where the file `ipc.h` was included, show all these lines. Maybe `ipc.h` gets included indirectly before you explicitly include it in your source file.

Answer (score 0):

These definitions should be at the top, before any headers are included.

Answer (score 0):

we can also specify the macro at the command line;
eg: if using _SVID_SOURCE :

gcc -std=c99 -D_SVID_SOURCE sema.c -o sema -lm -lc